# Trying to create a reset filter button with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, dropdown, reset

I'm trying to create a reset filter button which resets the dropdown box without reloading the page.

The reset filter button manages to reset the dropdown box back to default without reloading the page but after resetting the dropdown box, the html in the dropdown box doesn't work anymore.

**index.php**

```
 <button style="width: 100%; height: 40px" name="resetFilter" id="resetFilter">Reset filters</button>

          <section class="main2">
        <div class="wrapper-demo2">
          <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">
            <span class="transport">Select mode of transport</span>
              <ul class="dropdownTransport" tabindex="1">
                  <li value="Driving"><a href="#">Driving</a></li>
                  <li value="Transit"><a href="#">Transit</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        ​</div>
      </section>
    <script src="js/dropdown2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
$(function(e) {
   $('#resetFilter').click(function(e) {   
      var dropdownClone2 = $(".wrapper-demo2").clone();
      $(".wrapper-demo2").html(dropdownClone2);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**dropdown2.js**

```
  function DropDown2(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span.transport');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdownTransport > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
  }
  DropDown2.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
      var obj = this;

      obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
      });

      obj.opts.on('click',function(){
        var opt = $(this);
        obj.val = opt.text();
        obj.index = opt.index();
        obj.placeholder.text('Option: ' + obj.val);
      });
    },
    getValue : function() {
      return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
      return this.index;
    }
  }

  $(function() {

    var dd2 = new DropDown2( $('#dd2') );

    $(document).click(function() {
      // all dropdowns
      $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
    });

  });
```

Comment: At first glance, you probably want to replace your clone line with `$('.wrapper-demo2').children().clone();`.

Comment: Does `.clone()` really preserve your event handlers? (`obj.opts.on('click'`)

Comment: All events are destroyed when you `html(dropdownClone2)`, Try to `new DropDown2( $('#dd2') );` after .

Comment: [`clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) seems capable of copying events as well.

Comment: new DropDown2( $('#dd2') ); seems to be able to reset the filter but if i select an option after resetting the filter, javascript can't detect the option selected inside and console.log shows that it is undefined.

Comment: Did you try `clone(true)` as suggested by @Jeto?

Comment: tried that as well but the dropdown box doesn't reset at all.

Comment: @Syscall got it

Answer (score 1):

First, add a `data-initial-value` into your dd2 object to reset the span:

```
<div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1" data-initial-value="Select mode of transport">
```

When you clone your dropdown, all listeners are removed. So you have to init again, and clone the children :

```
$('#resetFilter').click(function(e) {   
  var dropdownClone2 = $('.wrapper-demo2').children().clone();
  $(".wrapper-demo2").html(dropdownClone2);
  new DropDown2( $('#dd2') ); // initialize the new DropDown
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And in the DropDown constructor :

```
function DropDown2(el) {
   this.dd = el;
   this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span.transport');
   this.placeholder.html(this.dd.attr("data-initial-value"));
```

---

Here is the full HTML/JS (all in one file) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <button style="width: 100%; height: 40px" name="resetFilter" id="resetFilter">Reset filters</button>
        <section class="main2">
        <div class="wrapper-demo2">
          <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1" data-initial-value="Select mode of transport">
            <span class="transport">Select mode of transport</span>
              <ul class="dropdownTransport" tabindex="1">
                  <li value="Driving"><a href="#">Driving</a></li>
                  <li value="Transit"><a href="#">Transit</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        ​</div>
      </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function(e) {
       $('#resetFilter').click(function(e) {
          var dropdownClone2 = $('.wrapper-demo2').children().clone();
          $(".wrapper-demo2").html(dropdownClone2);
          var dd2 = new DropDown2( $('#dd2') );

          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function DropDown2(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span.transport');
    this.placeholder.html(this.dd.attr("data-initial-value"));
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdownTransport > li');
    this.opts.removeClass("selected"); // <<<< NEW
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
  }
  DropDown2.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
      var obj = this;

      obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
      });

      obj.opts.on('click',function(){
        var opt = $(this);
        obj.val = opt.text();
        obj.index = opt.index();
        obj.placeholder.text('Option: ' + obj.val);
        obj.opts.removeClass("selected"); // <<<< NEW
        opt.addClass("selected"); // <<<< NEW
      });
    },
    getValue : function() {
      return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
      return this.index;
    }
  }

  $(function() {

    var dd2 = new DropDown2( $('#dd2') );

    $(document).click(function() {
      // all dropdowns
      $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
    });

  });
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i try to console.log the value inside the dd2 
via var transport = $('.dropdownTransport li.selected').attr('value'); 
it shows as undefined after i reset the filter.

Comment: still doesn't work unfortunately, still showing as undefined.

Comment: yup, used the one which has selected instead of active

Comment: @dythe I hope some things helps. Should I delete my answer?